# How to print in reciept printer with jzebra applet

Tags: java, javascript, codeigniter, printing, applet

After googling from last week, i didn't find anything helpful or well written answer, i am posting my question.
I want to make print from reciept printers on website, with jzebra applet.

I have tried the jzebra applet, it always says in firebug

```
TypeError: document.jzebra is undefined
```

What i have tried till now:
html code:

```
<applet name="jZebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="<?=base_url()?>jZebra/dist/jzebra.jar" width="10" height="10">
      <param name="printer" value="zebra">
    </applet>
```

javascript code:

```
function print_content(order_id){
         var html_to_print='';
          document.jzebra.append("PRINTED USING JZEBRA\n");
            document.jzebra.print();
}
```

And i also want to know how i can use this with wi-fi printers

Comment: Is your configuration correct? Is the applet running?

Comment: i think it's runing because it's not giving any error, if i pass wrong path in apple it shows error

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is case sensitive. So if you write `<applet name="jZebra">`, use like `document.jZebra..append(...)`

Comment: thanks it solve some problem atleast, but now i have connected it to normal printer only, it's not giving any error, and not even printing, and how do i do it ip address of a printer ??

Comment: I don't know well about jzebra, but perhaps ip address of a priter is needed on printer driver setup step. https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialRawXP#Steps https://code.google.com/p/jzebra/wiki/TutorialWebApplet

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to your second question:

> how do i do it ip address of a printer

There is a *relatively* new feature called `printToHost()`

```
// qz.printToHost(String hostName, int portNumber);
// qz.printToHost("192.168.254.254");   // Defaults to 9100
qz.printToHost("192.168.1.254", 9100);
```

Instead of using a locally installed printer (which is the most common method), this will instead open a socket to port 9100 and send your data directly.

If this `printToHost()` option is unavailable in your qz-print version, please upgrade to at least 1.8.0.